# Create Arraylist and add items to Listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I parsed several items with JSoup which i want to add to a listview, preferable through an arraylist like this:

```
End date: 08-10-2012
Left: € 38,50
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Result of JSoup as System.out.println:

```
End date: // td:eq(0)
Left:     // td:eq(0)
08-10-2012  // td:eq(1)
€ 38,50     // td:eq(1)
```

My code:

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        //publishProgress(false); 
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_top);
        ListView kp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.kpn);
        tv.setText("");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)");
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)"); 

        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) { 
            System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
            tv.setText(tdFromSecondColumn.text());
            //kp.setAdapter(adapter);
        } 
        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) { 
            System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
        }
```

Edit:

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        //publishProgress(false); 
        // create the grid item mapping
        ListView kp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.kpn);

        String[] from = new String[] {"col_1", "col_2"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.lbl_password, R.id.lbl_result };

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_top);
        tv.setText("");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)");
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)"); 

        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {
            map.put("col_1", tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
            fillMaps.add(map);

            System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
            tv.setText(tdFromSecondColumn.text());
            //kp.setAdapter(adapter);
        } 
        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) {
            map.put("col_2", tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
            fillMaps.add(map);

            System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, fillMaps, R.layout.main, from, to); 
        kp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

App crashes, Logcat:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9105): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object must not be null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) as your list adapter. Just map the values in your arraylist to the appropriate parts of the view you're using for each row in your list. Here's an [example](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html) of using a SimpleAdapter. Here's an [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) of using a different type of adapter, an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), that might be of even more use to you.

Comment: Hi Kurtis,
Thx for the reply.
Can you give a small example code?

Comment: Did you not see the example I included in my answer, or was it to big?

Comment: Yes, i saw it but i am not getting it right.
I already have some code, please find it in my edited code.
Maybe you could correct it?

Comment: I included some more examples in my answer now.

Comment: Hi Kurtis,
I am almost there, but i can`t compile as if get the message Constructor SimpleAdapter is undefined??
See my edited code.

Comment: OK, i got it but know the app crashed.
Logcat: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9105): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object must not be null
Please help.

Comment: @Lars As this in a new question if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi Kurtis,
I finally got it but it keeps teasing me, i have to work around with the layouts as i have a AbsoluteLayout in 1 xml file.
It shows the items only partialy.
Thx again Kurtis for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest SimpleAdapter too; see this well made [example](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/) I follwed when I needed to learn this adapter.

And it will be easy for you to reuse the code you have already written because it's quite similar.

Comment: Hi Mangusto,
Thank you for the reply, i already found it but at the code SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.grid_item, from, to); i get a error constrcutor undefined.
Please see my edited code.
Can you help?

Comment: Try defining fillMaps as

` ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); `

Comment: Hi Mangusto,
I already solved it, should not be: new SimpleAdapter(this, .., ..) but new SimpleAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, .., ..) 
Thx anyhow.